# Magento 2.3.4 version product thumbnails & product image issue on product detail page [PDP]

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, product-page, media-images

I have just updated Magento to 2.3.4 but facing an issue of images on Product Detail Page(PDP).

I have changed the layout of thumbnails as vertical. After changing the thumbnail image layout on PDP product images are not displaying.

If I kept the layout as horizontal then gallery images & product image is showing. But this does not happen with the vertical layout.

I have checked with galley.phtml file as well as by changing its JSON but still facing the issues.

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Thank you.